# How to insert strings on a Python MySQL Query?

Tags: python, mysql

I am Python newbie and I am trying to query a MySQL database. The MySQL syntax is tested on PHP and it worked, but the Python parameters are new to me and they're giving me an error. Could you help me?

```
pom = "Alcobaça"
data_inicial = "2012-12-01"
data_final = "2012-12-05"

cur.execute("SELECT DATE(DTM), POM, ROUND(MIN(TMP),1)
FROM dados_meteo WHERE POM =%s
AND DATE(DTM) >=%s AND DATE(DTM) <=%s"
%(pom,data_inicial,data_final))
```

Comment: Please post the errors with your questions. :)

Comment: I am using Flask to run it locally on mycomputer. I just have a 500 Internal Server Error on the browser. Sorry...

Comment: Where do you open the connection ?

Comment: import MySQLdb
 
 db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "","sensorzapp")

 cur = db.cursor()

Comment: Before, of course ;-)

Comment: If you're using Flask, set `app.debug = True`; otherwise you won't get the stack trace.

Comment: @JacobBudin I've done it. But can I paste the error message here?

Comment: Here is the error message https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8905574

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using the MySQLdb module. If so, you can (and should) use `execute`'s built-in second parameter, and pass the inputs as a tuple like so:

```
c.execute( \
    "SELECT DATE(DTM), POM, ROUND(MIN(TMP),1) FROM \
        dados_meteo WHERE POM = %s AND DATE(DTM) >= %s AND DATE(DTM) <= %s", \
    (pom, data_inicial, data_final))
```

Do this instead of using  `%` to format the string in-line. Providing the data to MySQLdb allows it to quote and escape your strings. Right now, the strings in your query are neither quoted or escaped.

Comment: Thank you. Now I get a message- TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: @Hugo Are you missing any commas? Did you remove the extra whitespace and indentation that was in my original answer? (It was only formatted like that to better show the code. I've added backslashes.)

Comment: I am using a single line on Sublime Text to avoid errors

Comment: Should I change the file from UTF-8 for another one?